# mongodb Aggregation Pipeline to create a list of values from multiple nested document properties

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell

I have two collections, db.items and db.data, in the following format:

```
// db.items document (configuration-level information such as name, settings, user, etc.)
{
    _id: #id,
    ...
}

// db.data document (data for the a configuration)
{
    ...,
    item: #id, // reference to _id of db.item doc
    grouping_1: [
        { name: "A", item: "ObjectId()" },
        { name: "B", item: "ObjectId()" }
    ],
    grouping_2: [
        { name: "C", item: "ObjectId()" },
        { name: "D", item: "ObjectId()" }
    ]
}
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to use the [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) to feed a db.item doc a list of the db.data "name" props.

```
// db.items document desired result
{
    _id: #id,
    names: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
    ...
}
```

Queries such as `db.data.find( { item: #id }, { _id: 0, "grouping_1.name": 1, "grouping_2.name": 1 } )` for some reason return sets like this `{ "grouping_1": [ { "name": "A" }, { "name": "B" } ], "grouping_2" : [ { "name": "C" }, { "name", "D" } ] }`

**I would prefer to see the implementation using both the shell and C# driver (2.10); however, if you can only provide one/that's too much to ask for I'll happily accept either one.**

Edit:
I was thinking restructuring my schema to be something like this would possibly make more sense/be easier to work with.

```
{
    ...,
    grouping_1: {
        "A": "ObjectId()",
        "B": "ObjectId()"
    },
    grouping_2: {
        "C": "ObjectId()",
        "D": "ObjectId()"
    }
}
```

Edit 2:
For anyone who has a schema like i suggested in the first edit, [here's the solution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ED6WUjWhDOH)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe this pipeline will get you the result expected:

```
db.Item.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            _id: ObjectId("5e6f98e41b70ea2c14c208b9")
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Data",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "item",
            as: "data"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            names: {
                $map: {
                    input: {
                        $concatArrays: [
                            { $arrayElemAt: ["$data.grouping_1", 0] },
                            { $arrayElemAt: ["$data.grouping_2", 0] }]
                    },
                    in: '$$this.name'
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/H3Q3N0-P9JB

here's a [good way](https://dev.to/djnitehawk/overcoming-the-limitations-of-mongodb-c-driver-1110) to execute this pipeline in c#